# Dynamic detection of AngularJS table property

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, csv

I have a table that I display using AngularJS. This table is a csv file as an array of arrays that lists out each row of the original CSV file. In my front end, I am using Angular to parse this data, but I need to manipulate one of the columns from the csv data in a special way. The problem is that I do not know where the column will be, so I need to figure out in angular when I have bumped into the right column.

```
<div ng-init='csv_array = <?php echo h( json_encode( $csv_array ) ) ?>'></div>              
<table class="table">
    <tr>    
        <td ng-repeat="row in header_list" >{{row}}</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr ng-repeat="csv_row in csv_array | filter:searchText ">
        // what I have now
        <td ng-repeat="cell in csv_row" >{{cell}}</td>

        // I want something like
        // <td ng-repeat="cell in csv_row" >{{cell.name == foo then hello else cell}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I load in the CSV file through PHP. I need to write the AngularJS to detect that the header is called 'foo' and then I need to do some special processing on just that row. Is there a way to use AngularJS to detect the `csv_row` name that is being processed and then is there a way to do special processing on just that row? I'm new to AngularJS, so its possible that this is really easy.

Comment: I would suggest editing the table data in your controller.

Comment: You can use `ng-if` directive for that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @javaCity That sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: Cool but be careful not to use divs inside tds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` directive for that.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

*(For the sake of thread completeness, I've copied my comment here)*